# When is $Ind(C)$ small?

Tags: ct.category-theory, accessible-categories

Let $C$ be a small category. Then $Ind(C)$ is the free completion of $C$ under filtered colimits. My sense is that typically, $Ind(C)$ is a large category. But sometimes it is small. For example, if $C$ is a poset, then $Ind(C)$ is the (small) poset of filters in $C$. But I think $C$ need not be a poset for $Ind(C)$ to be small. Another way of saying that $Ind(C)$ is small is to say that $Ind(C)$ is a small, finitely-accessible category. So my questions are:

**Questions:**

1. What is an example of a small, finitely-accessible category which is not a poset?
2. Are there criteria on $C$ for $Ind(C)$ to be small more general than $C$ being a poset?
3. Better yet, is there a characterization of those $C$ for which $Ind(C)$ is small?
4. From the other direction, is there a characterization of small, finitely accessible categories?

Note that if $C$ is a small, idempotent-complete category, then $C$ is $(|C|+\aleph_0)^{++}$-accessible. But this bound never gets down to $\aleph_0$.

Comment: Do you have any examples of non-poset small categories $C$ such that ${\rm Ind}(C)$ is small?

Comment: I think the free split idempotent is finitely accessible. Call the maps $i: A \to X$, $r : X \to A$, with $ri = \mathrm{id}_A$. It has filtered colimits: the colimit of a chain is $A$ if there is a cofinal sequence of $ir$'s and trivial otherwise. $X$ is finitely accessible: for a nontrivial filtered colimit $Hom(X,\varinjlim X_i) = \varinjlim Hom(X,X_i) = \ast$.